# Real state project data structure suggestion

Tags: php, drupal, rets

I am working in a real state project (linux, drupal, php 5, mysql) and I need to pull data in from the local mls sytem.

What data structure should I use IDX or RETS? (and why?)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. Don't know these format myself (therefore sorry if this answer won't be satisfying to you), but a quick search revealed few already existing Drupal modules which seem to do what you are looking for:

- dRealty IDX - http://drupal.org/project/drealty
- MLS - http://drupal.org/project/mls

and few example discussions on the subject:

- http://drupal.org/node/658662
- http://groups.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/5439
- http://groups.drupal.org/node/9450
- etc...

But perhaps you've already seen them?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, IDX is an NAR policy and not a technology.  RETS is a protocol for sharing property listing data over the net.

When then term is misused and not relating to the NAR policy, IDX is meant to use a limited set of data generally useful for advertising purposes only.  RETS, when misused in a similar matter, may mean the full feed of data.

Answer (score 1):

For `MLS/IDX` Data Downloading from server RETS IQ in Java is good.

Data Structure in Storage format

```
<MLSNAME>/DataDownload/
         /DataProcessed/
```